# AWS Lambda returning JSON data as string

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

I am using AWS Lambda to create my APIs and want to return an array's data in JSON format. However, when I call the lambda, it is able to return the required JSON data but it is coming as a string in double quotes. I tried running the same code in my Python IDE and everything works fine but when I try to return it in Lambda it is coming as a string.
Has this got something to do with how Lambda handles the `return` statement in Python functions? 
This is how I'm returning data in my Lambda:

```
return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'headers': {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
            },
            'body': json.dumps(json_data,default = myconverter)
        }
```

Here `json_data` is a python list which is populated with the data that is being retrieved from the database for the specific unique ID passed by the user and `myconverter` is the JSON encoder that I've written.

The output that I'm getting is:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  },
  "body": "[{\"Dp_Record_Id\": 2, \"DP_TYPE\": \"NSDL\", \"DP_ID\": \"40877589\", \"CLIENT_ID\": \"1232\", \"Default_flag\": \"Y\"}]"
}
```

Here, I want the `"body"` to just return an array of the data without double quotes, like this:

```
"body": [{\"Dp_Record_Id\": 2, \"DP_TYPE\": \"NSDL\", \"DP_ID\": \"40877589\", \"CLIENT_ID\": \"1232\", \"Default_flag\": \"Y\"}]
```

Please let me know if this is possible and how can it be done.
Any help on this would be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can just do `'body': json_data`. I tested this now in my λ function:

#### Lambda function

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    json_data = [{"Dp_Record_Id": 2, 
                  "DP_TYPE": "NSDL",
                  "DP_ID": "40877589", 
                  "CLIENT_ID": "1232", 
                  "Default_flag": "Y"}]

    return {'statusCode': 200,
            'headers': {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
            },
            'body': json_data
        }
```

#### Result

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  },
  "body": [
    {
      "Dp_Record_Id": 2,
      "DP_TYPE": "NSDL",
      "DP_ID": "40877589",
      "CLIENT_ID": "1232",
      "Default_flag": "Y"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I forgot to mention that the data stored in the json_data dictionary is being populated by my SQL query. Have editted the question, please view it

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the client is not understanding the type correctly, try adding the following into the `"headers"` dictionary:

```py
"content-type":"application/json",
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue while I was creating an API by doing things from my memory. Posting this answer for my future self and others.

The issue was that whatever I return in the lambda is getting passed as response to the API. Instead only the data inside `body` should be passed as response.

This was happening because when I created the resource I forgot to check the checkbox to ***Use Lambda Proxy Integration***. Here is what you have to do:

1. Delete your existing method and create a new one. This time make sure you check ***Use Lambda Proxy Integration***.[image: API Gateway with Lambda proxy]
2. Create a deployment to your stage. Until this is done, the change will not reflect. This is where I got stuck and spend most of my time.